# In-App Billing for Beta Users

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

My Android app is on open beta in the Google Play Store.

Do beta-testers have to pay for In-App Billing purchases? 
If the beta-testers then install the release version of the app, does the IAB carry-over?

Could you suggest a strategy where I am trying to avoid having my beta testers pay for something they can't use when they update, and conversely I don't want to give all the IAB for free.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is stated here:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

You have to read the full article so I can't point the most important things out, sorry.